# Windows 10 (Bootcamp) : No options under "Region & Language page" in Settings

Tags: boot-camp, windows-10-v1803

I installed latest update of Windows 10 : `1803, April 2018 update`.

I observed my `Language Settings` to be wrong. So, I tried to change it by going to

`Region & Language page` under `Time & Language` settings in main `Settings`.

And found that `Region & Language` Page is **absolutely blank**. It has no options to change.

[image: Region & Language page under settings]

I assume it's unique to the version of Windows given the fact that I'm running it in Bootcamp. So, **How can I change the Region & Language Settings by command line or Powershell or from Settings App ?**

Comment: try [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-change-display-80448f7f)

Comment: @magicandre1981 It would be helpful to post the contents of the script, and a brief explanation as an answer to this question.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt I'm not the author of the script, I used search and found this script.